# How to integrate get_post_time with date_i18n function?

Tags: date, translation, localization

I have date format and would like to translate to another language with `date_i18n` function how can I integrate with get_post_time here is my code :

```
$time = get_post_time('F j, Y', true,$newspost['ID']);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the fourth parameter for `get_post_time()`:

```
$time = get_post_time(
    'F j, Y',      // format
    TRUE,          // GMT
    get_the_ID(),  // Post ID
    TRUE           // translate, use date_i18n()
);
```

`get_post_time()` calls `mysql2date()` internally, and it passes the `$translate` argument through. In `mysql2date()` we find this:

```
if ( $translate )
    return date_i18n( $format, $i );
```

So, all you need is a single `TRUE`.

For a test, try this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_100266_i18n_time' );

/**
 * Prepend the post content with translated post time.
 *
 * @wp-hook the_content
 * @param   string $content
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_100266_i18n_time( $content )
{
    $time = get_post_time(
        'F j, Y',      // format
        TRUE,          // GMT
        get_the_ID(),  // Post ID
        TRUE           // translate, use date_i18n()
    );

    return "<p>$time</p>$content";
}
```

Then install at least one other language and the plugin [WCM User Language Switcher](https://github.com/wecodemore/wcm_lang_switch). Viewing the front end, we get different month names when we switch the language now.

`get_post_modified_time()` works with the same arguments.

Comment: Hi, it works nice.. " $time = get_post_time('j M Y', true,$newspost->ID,true);  " Thank you very much 5 stars