# How to change date_format in entry-info

Tags: posts

So, i need help with a problem.
I'm using Project Ar2 Theme in wordpress, and i have a doubt about the theme.
I want to translate some part of theme in  where I managed to translate 'posted' to 'postado', but I want to translate the format_date.
For example: www.neilgaiman.com.br 
Confira sinopse do episódio de Doctor Who
Postado **on 27 de April de 2013** how becames its in portuguese?

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100275/73)?

Comment: Yeah, i believe. Do you know what is the correct file I need to change?

Comment: No, I don’t know that theme. Find occurrences of `the_date()` or `the_time()`.

Comment: I founded the_date() in archive.php, is this the correct file? (sorry, I'm newbie)

Comment: Try it. Make a backup of the theme and start playing.

Comment: Doesn't work =/ there are another solution?