# setlocale for date

Tags: translation, date-time, language

So I purchased a premium wordpress theme, but I can't get through its Polish localization - the dates outside the_time or the_date are displaying in English (default server's language). I read that I have to use setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL'); to change it, but I don't know in which file or where it should be included and/or if I need something more. Below is an excerpt of code displaying English date:

```
$event_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_date');
$event_from_time = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_from_time');
$event_to_time = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_to_time');
$event_address = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_address');

echo date('j F Y', strtotime($event_date[0])).'  '.$event_from_time[0].' do '.$event_to_time[0];
```

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `date_i18n( $format, $i );`

```
echo date_i18n('j F Y', strtotime( $event_date[0] ) ) 
    . '  '
    . date_i18n('j F Y', strtotime( $event_from_time[0] ) ) 
    . ' do '
    . date_i18n('j F Y', strtotime( $event_to_time[0] ) );
```

See also: [How to integrate get_post_time with date_i18n function?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100266/how-to-integrate-get-post-time-with-date-i18n-function)

Comment: thx for the answer and the read, it works great. however any idea why date_i18n does not work with the abbreviated month ('M')?

Comment: @gipson `M` should work fine (not every format will since `date_i18n()` essentially emulates format support rather than using native PHP stuff), just tested.

Comment: @Rarst My bad. Thx for your help guys!